# Possible to have a static public IP and a private IP behind a CGNAT on the same router?

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing

### Background

I recently acquired a single static public IP from my ISP. Prior to this, my router was assigned a private IP that was behind a CGNAT. Staying behind a CGNAT offered a certain degree of anonymity, as a single IP was shared among multiple customers, and if I ever needed a new public IP, I could just reboot my router.

### Problem

I want to keep using the private IP and the public IP both such that all traffic from say 192.168.1.0 is routed through the private IP and all traffic from 192.168.2.0 is routed through the public IP. While my current router probably doesn't have any functionality for this, I'll soon be deploying pfSense on a Dell Optiplex. What are the possible solutions to achieve said functionality?

### Can these solutions work?

- The cheapest solution could be to just somehow do this in software (I don't know how though), the Optiplex will have only two NICs, one as the WAN port and the other as the LAN port.
- If the first one doesn't work, maybe the Optiplex could have three NICs, two as WAN ports and one as a LAN port. Like this: 
  [image: ISP -> Switch -> Two Wan NICs in Optiplex] 
  but this will increase the cost because I'll have to buy an additional network card.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use a VPN when you wish to stay anonymous.

Comment: @harrymc I don't want to pay for a VPN as I intend on using it 24x7 and no free VPN would allow that much traffic.

Comment: A free alternative is Tor, although the bandwidth is not high.